# How to modify an ELF file in a way that changes data length of parts of the file?

Tags: linux, elf

I'm trying to modify the executable contents of my own ELF files to see if this is possible. I have written a program that reads and parses ELF files, searches for the code that it should update, changes it, then writes it back after updating the sh_size field in the section header.

However, this doesn't work. If I simply exchange some bytes, with other bytes, it works. However, if I change the size, it fails. I'm aware of that some sh_offsets are immediately adjacent to each other; however this shouldn't matter when I'm *reducing* the size of the executable code.

Of course, there might be a bug in my program (or more than one), but I've already painstakingly gone through it.

Instead of asking for help with debugging my program I'm just wondering, is there anything else than the sh_size field I need to update in order to make this work (when reducing the size)? Is there anything that would make changing the length fail other than that field?

Edit:

It seems that Andy Ross was perfectly correct. Even in this very simple program I have come across some indirect addressing in __libc_start_main that I cannot trivially modify to update the offset it will reach.

I was curious though, what would be the best approach to still trying to get as far as possible with this problem? I know I cannot solve this in every case, but for some simple programs, it should be possible to update what is required to make it run? Should I try writing my own virtual machine or try developing a "debugger" that would replace each suspected problem instruction with INT 3? Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of ELF file is it? How did you produce it? Is it a dynamically linked or a statically linked executable, or some shared object? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12551737/841108

Comment: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text segment is likely internally linked with relative offsets.  So one function might be trying to jump to, say, "current address plus 194 bytes".  If you move things around such that the jump target is now 190 bytes, you will obviously break things.  The same is true of constant data on some architectures (e.g. x86-64 but not i686). There is no simple way short of a complete disassembly to know where the internal references are, and in fact it's computationally undecidable to find them all (i.e. trying to figure out all possible jump targets of a runtime-computed branch is the Halting Problem).

Basically, this isn't solvable in the general case, so if you have an ELF binary from someone else you're trying to patch, you'll need to try other techniques.  But with (great!) care it's possible to produce a library where all internal references go through the GOT/PLT which can be sliced up and relinked like this.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The workaround would be: if it shrinks, fill with nops; if it grows, substitute by a call and put the real code elsewhere; and hope no one jumps into the middle of the modified section of code.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks for the input. I was just doing this on a simple hello world program actually; I wouldn't have thought it could mess up some relative offsets in the init code or something like that. I get a fault in: 0x00000000004005f0 in __libc_csu_init ()
=> 0x00000000004005f0 <__libc_csu_init+0>:       6c     ins    BYTE PTR es:[rdi],dx
I don't see how any relative offsets that might be prior to main would be affected by the size of main?

Answer (score 4):

> is there anything else than the sh_size field I need to update in order to make this work

It sounds like you are patching a fully-linked binary (`ET_EXEC` or `ET_DYN`). Please note that `.sh_size` is *not* used for anything after the static link is done. You can strip the entire section table, and the binary will continue to work fine. What matters at runtime are the *segments* in the ELF, not *sections*.

ELF stands for *executable* and *linking* format, and the *executable* and *linking* form "dual nature" of the ELF. Sections are used at (static) *link* time to combine into segments; which are used at execution time (aka runtime, aka dynamic linking time).

Of course you haven't told us exactly what your patching strategy is when you are shrinking your binary, and in what way the result is broken. It is very likely that Andy Ross's answer is the real cause of your breakage.